# Sum of all from a column PHP array

Tags: php, mysqli

I have worked out an average based on scores by user like so:

```
      $score1 = $row["score1"];
      $score2 = $row["score2"];
      $score3 = $row["score3"];
      $score4 = $row["score4"];
      $score5 = $row["score5"];
      $score6 = $row["score6"];
      $score7 = $row["score7"];
      $score8 = $row["score8"];

      $sum = $score1 + $score2 + $score3 + $score4 + $score5 + $score6 + $score7 + $score8;
      $totalAverage = $sum / 8;
```

This gives me the average of each person. What I need to do is get the total average by adding up everyones score and outputting the end total if that makes sense?

This is my select request:

```
$sql = "SELECT member.id, member.firstName, member.lastName, compScore.score1, compScore.score2, compScore.score3, compScore.score4, compScore.score5, compScore.score6, compScore.score7, compScore.score8, compScore.memberId, teamMember.memberId, teamMember.teamId
        FROM member
        LEFT JOIN compScore
        ON member.id = compScore.memberId
        LEFT JOIN teamMember
        ON teamMember.memberId = member.id
        WHERE teamMember.teamId = $teamData";
```

I've got a scores table which collects all the scores (always only ever be a set of 8) but get everyones scores and then make an average of them all.

Comment: For your first code block just do `extract($row);` and remove all binding lines. if only the scores are in the `$row` array you can do `$total = array_sum($row)/count($row);`;

Comment: How do you mean sorry?

Comment: so remove $score1, $score2 etc etc

Comment: `extract($row);` creates all varaibles of all fields in the array like  `$score1,...` http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: the issue I face is that by doing that its going to drag in ALL the selects where as I just want to pick out the scores.